# Android UI Tests fail due to mockwebserver

Tags: android, android-espresso, okhttp, dagger-hilt, mockwebserver

Actually in order to run my test on github action, i need to manipulate my test to following repo,

Ui Test File:
https://github.com/TheReprator/Wipro/tree/mockwebserver/appModules/factList/src/androidTest/kotlin/reprator/wipro/factlist/test

Repo: https://github.com/TheReprator/Wipro

Branch: mockwebserver

My all ui test pass locally with branch(master) but when i run it with github action, all ui test case fails.

Looking forward for a solution.

My issue on github:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6733

Regards,

Vikram Singh

Answer (score 0):

When using mockWebServer.start() you should use mockWebServer.url(path) to give you the url, not hardcode 0 in the URL.

See https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver

```
  // Start the server.
  server.start();

  // Ask the server for its URL. You'll need this to make HTTP requests.
  HttpUrl baseUrl = server.url("/v1/chat/");
```

Comment: but with server.start(), i am getting the error as, java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL port: "0"

Comment: and i am using Dispatcher,  with mockwebserver

Comment: Please have a look at it, i  had changed my code, but still not working